# Consonant-Only & Vowel-Only N-Grams List?

Tags: n-grams

I've found many different N-Gram lists, but never of any complete consonant-only or vowel-only N-grams. Lists generally combine consonants with vowels. Some lists also document what the pronunciation n-grams would be rather than the spelling. For clarity, here's what I'm looking for:

**In the word "miaouing",**

- **"m" is a consonant-only 1-gram**
- **"iaoui" is a vowel-only 5-gram**
- **"ng" is a consonant-only 2-gram**

Does anyone know what I can find a complete, or near complete, list of such N-grams of english?

Comment: This might be difficult since, as mentioned in the answers to [Impossible bigrams in the English Language](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4082), such lists can change depending on what rare words you include. I'm not sure I understand why a list that combines consonants with vowels would be unususable for your purposes; can't you just take such a list and use some program to automatically remove the ngrams that contain both consonants and vowels?

Comment: @sumelic I could, & I might resort to that. It just would've been simpler if someone else had done it already, haha. Yes, of course it's always an issue regarding what corpus/dictionary you gather data from. For this sort of thing, I'm inclined for either the Concise Oxford English Dictionary or the Enable2k North American word list. If I compile this myself, it'll likely be from the latter.

Comment: 2 reasons why that may be: 1 vowel vs consonant is a bit context dependent in English, not a simple mapping 2 "n-gram" lists whether char- or word-level usually make no assumptions about these sorts of attributes.  You may have better luck with "segments" or "sequences" or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is unreasonable to expect to find a ready-made list of that kind. Just take a generic n-gram list and use some filters (e.g. `grep -E -v '[aeiou]'` to get consonant-only patterns) to extract the n-grams of interest. The letter `y` may be a tricky case due to its dual nature, and you may even argue about the letter `i` in words like *motion* or the `gh` in words like *sigh*.